# Tolua++ and __tostring

Tags: tolua++

Can anyone here help me with use of tolua++ and __tostring?

If I try to set the __tostring property on the metatable of a Lua object bound from a C++ object, I get a crash.

E.g.

```
local x = foo.new() -- foo bound from tolua++
getmetatable(x).__tostring = function(t) end
```

...causes a crash.

It seems that setting metatable functions that already exist, like __eq, is OK... whilst setting a function that does not yet exist, like __tostring or 'foobar' causes a crash.

Comment: Does `setmetatable` work?

Comment: Yes, but if you change the entire metatable of a userdata object bound by tolua, you will lose everything tolua has bound!

Comment: Then copy it to some other object, change it there, then use setmetatable?

Comment: Tim, what if you set __tostring to some "default" function, like `function(t) return t end`; as far as I understand, you should be able to change its value then.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution to my own question...

I can simply bind a function called "__tostring" from my C++ base classes, using tolua. This then appears on the class metatable, so is called (as expected) from Lua if an object of that class is printed.

Futhermore, I can then replace the function on the Lua side (e.g. using getmetatable(foo).__tostring = somenewfunction) without any problems.

I'd still be interested to know why the crash occurs if the __tostring function is not explicitly bound usi